# react-router-v4: how to pass this.state data to a component that is being triggered only by the route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Im working on a **react** project, with **react's state**, and with **react-router-dom v4**.

Im trying to understand how can I pass the app's state to a **not child component** that is being rendered in my `<Route path="/newpage" component={parentlessComponent}>`

How do I pass data to a ***parentless component***?

Comment: I am new to react. Here is a work around,  if you are not storing any crucial data in app's state, you can use _localStorage_.

Comment: Are u using redux?

Comment: no, im using react's state

Answer (score 2):

You can render your   `parentlessComponent` using `render` and pass it the component state and other data that you want.

```
<Route path='/newpage' render={() => (
      <parentlessComponent {...this.state} data={extraProps}/>
    )}/>
```

And in your `parentlessComponent` you can access it using props.

```
class parentlessComponent extends React.component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.parentData= this.props.data;
        this.parentState= this.props.some_parent_state;
    }    
  }
```

Comment: what if my app.js and my routes.js are in separeted files?
can I extract just the state out of the App component, so I could import it to the Routes file and pass it as props to the parentlessComponent ?

Comment: @ueeiee create one class with getter and setter with this state data and share between app,js and route.js.You need to create singleton class

Answer (score 1):

You could use the render prop instead and do something like this :

```
<Route path="/newpage" render={()=><ParentlessComponent someProp={true} />} />
```

There are multiple ways you could do this. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105#issuecomment-291834881).

Comment: my routes are on a different module, so how can I "extract" the app's state, 
so I could pass it as a props into the render method ?

Comment: If the props are dependent on the app state, you should have the apps state where you define your routes. Let's say you have your routes defined in App.js. If you're using react-redux you can connect() your app and access your store. If not, you'll just pass the state from where you have it.

Comment: I see. but what can i do if i want, to keep my routes separated from my app.js? so I'll have a cleaner code, then what ? can I "extract" the state out of the app component independently?

Comment: You'll have to use something like react-redux. And then you can have access to your state if you connect your App to it as well.

Comment: Can you share your source code structure/folder structure? Trying to understand what you are trying to do..